# How to calcaulate tf-idf value?

Tags: nlp, tf-idf

My calculation is :

TF(d) = 3/5

IDF(d) = ln(4/3)

TF * IDF = 0.17, but that is not the answer, 0 is not correct answer.

#### Question:

The following question will ask you about a corpus with the following documents.

```
Document 1: a a b c
Document 2: a c c c d e f
Document 3: a c d d d
Document 4: a d f
```

What is the tf-idf value for "d" in Document 3?
Round answers to two decimal places. Use the natural logarithm (log base e) when taking a logarithm.

select:

```
0.00
0.57
0.69
0.86
2.07
3.47
6.00
```

Comment: Not a programming question, better ask on https://datascience.stackexchange.com/ There's probably an error in the question, you have the correct answer 0.17,

Answer (score 0):

TF = (number of time the term appears in the document) / (total number of terms in the document)

IDF = log( (number of the document in the corpus) / (number of documents in the corpus contain the term) )

The TF-IDF of a term is calculated by multiplying TF and IDF scores.

```
TF-IDF = TF * IDF
```

You can calculate by that however, some librariess use natural logarithm in addition, one can be added to the denominator as follows in order to avoid division by zero.

IDF = log( (number of the document in the corpus) / (number of documents in the corpus contain the term + 1) )

Exp, Imagine the term x appears 20 times in a document that contains a total of 100 words. So, TF is :

```
TF = 20/100 = 0.2
```

Assume a collection of related documents contains 10,000 documents. If 100 documents out of 10,000 documents contain the term x, So IDF is :

```
IDF = log(10000/100) = 2
```

By multiplying these two quantities, we can calculate the TF-IDF score for the x term for the document.

```
TF-IDF = 0.2 * 2 = 0.4
```